# How to Verify smart contracts deployed on polygon scan?

Tags: contract-deployment, contract-verification, polygon

we have deployed solidity contract to polygonscan, but for some reason, the smart contracts with imports cannot be verified. Has anyone else experienced this?

Comment: You just need to select multiple files upload instead of single file while verification

Comment: There is nothing special about PolygonScan that is different to how verifications work on Etherscan. Check out [hardhat-etherscan](https://github.com/nomiclabs/hardhat/tree/master/packages/hardhat-etherscan) and [multisol](https://github.com/paulrberg/multisol).